# Can I set up UCP (Universal Control Plane) in Docker Community Version?

Tags: docker

Can I set up UCP (Universal Control Plane) in Docker Community Version? Or do I need Docker Enterprise version to set up UCP?

Comment: [UCP](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/) is a Docker EE feature.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Universal Control Plane (UCP) is the enterprise-grade cluster management solution from Docker.

Comment: No information about UCP  found in official website `https://docs.docker.com/`. Has it been deprecated?